# Zend Framework - How routing is done in ZF 1.12?

Tags: zend-framework

I was going through the Zend document but I didn't get clear idea how **routing** is done in Zend framework 1.12.

What I understand from the document is when we hit the URL in the browser then request is going the index.php in public folder.

But I am not getting how Zend framework decomposes the URL and calls the particular controller and action.

Eg. 
consider the URL: `http://zendtutorial.local/blog/new`

How Zend evaluates **newAction from BlogController**

Comment: If you have the choice, I suggest not to put too much effort in ZF1. The architecture is outdated and many components are buggy. I suggest you to have a look into ZF3/Zend-Express or rather Symfony.

Comment: You are right. But I am working on the project where we are using the old Zend framework version i.e. 1.12, Hence I have no choice :( .

Comment: Oh I feel pity for you, I know the struggle :) Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When We hit the URL First following things happens:

1. Very first index.php in public directory gets called.
2. In Index.php the constants like APPLICATION_PATH, APPLICATION_ENV are defined and Application object gets created.
3. The settings in the application.ini file get initialized.

   - application.ini contains all the information like the default controller, default modules, database settings, etc.
4. Then the bootstrap function of Zend_Application gets called.
5. This function calls the Bootstrap class from bootstrap.php.
6. Then run() method of Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap gets called.

   - Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap :: run() method gets called.
7. Finally, **dispatch()** method of Zend_Controller_Front gets called.
8. dispatch() method routes the requested URL to specific controller and action.

Comment: Good explanation step by step! Maybe add one or two more steps how the request with controller and action is mapped to XyController.php xyAction .htaccess is only for Apache (sidenote).

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Thank you, Dan. I have edited my answer for your concern regarding .htaccess.